# Autocomplete jQueryUI appears below the lower edge of visible screen in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have problem with Autocomplete, it works well in all browsers except for IE. I have it positioned inside `<td>` (and `<tr>` and `<table>` of course) that is inside `<div>` that has CSS like this:

```
left: 10px; top: 400px; position: absolute; width: 350px;
```

none of its parrent elements have position/width modified in any way.. Yet when I type into the input that is autocompleted the selection list appears right under lower edge of the screen (no matter where that is in relation to input element).

Don't know if this has some inpact but the input and it's parrent `<div>` are hidden and shown dynamically (using prototype).. jQuery is used by using var $j = jQuery.noConflict().

Do you have any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that might be interested..
This was bug, that was fixed in newer version of jQueryUI.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a bit vague but I'll just point out that when absolutely positioning an element within another element the parent element must be relatively positioned.